# Not Able to Access AWS S3 bucket using AssumeRole by User

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS Service, I am doing some R&D on IAM.
I created one IAM user and IAM role(with Full S3 Read permission) and attach that IAM User with Role. I am using Spring boot application trying to connect that bucket with IAM user using STS assume Role.
But I am getting below error:

```html
om.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: 15G2FVKSWVYQNXXXX;
```

and I have verified that secretkey and access key are correct. may by the access key.
@Note: S3 bucket/IAM user/IAM role are in same aws account.

I know we can directly attach policy to user and fetch the bucket, but I want to try with assume role in same account.
below is my code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

            AWSSecurityTokenService stsclient= AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(getAWSCredentials("AKIAWEBTXXXXXXEDTIGNM", "KJR1e6eqk7schchdjhdyIf8R2FJQ6i")))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName("us-west-2"))
                .build();
            

            AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest= new AssumeRoleRequest().withDurationSeconds(3600).withRoleArn("arn:aws:iam::421XXXXX2511:role/s3_readonly_access_role").withRoleSessionName("test-session");
            AssumeRoleResult roleResult=stsclient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
            Credentials creds= roleResult.getCredentials();
            AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credProvider= new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicSessionCredentials(creds.getAccessKeyId(),creds.getSecretAccessKey(),creds.getSessionToken()));
            
            AmazonS3 s3=AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(getAWSCredentials(credProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId(),credProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey())))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName("us-west-2"))
                .build();

            List<Bucket> buckets=   s3.listBuckets();
            for(Bucket bucket:buckets){
                System.out.println(bucket.getName());
            }
        }catch(AmazonS3Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static AWSCredentials getAWSCredentials(String accessKey, String secretKey) {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(
                accessKey,
                secretKey);
    }
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: **Side-note:** You should never need to provide your credentials in the code itself. Instead, you can store them in a credentials file. The easiest way to do this is to run the AWS CLI `aws configure` command. Then, your code will automatically use those stored credentials.

Comment: The `.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(getAWSCredentials(credProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId(),credProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey())))` is missing the session token. Overall you are doing **waaaay too much** credential handling here. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789429/assume-role-with-spring-cloud-aws-autoconfiguration how to properly pass the credentials from STS to the S3 client.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein at  List<Bucket> buckets=   s3.listBuckets(); line i am getting this error.

Comment: You are using V1 - which is NOT best practice. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have this exact use case as part of the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) - which uses **AWS SDK for Java v2**. V1 is NOT recommended to use anymore as specified here in this [AWS page](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples#aws-sdk-code-examples).

This example shows you how to perform these tasks:

1. Creates a user that has no permissions.
2. Creates a role and policy that grants Amazon S3 permissions.
3. Creates a role.
4. Grants the user permissions.
5. Gets temporary credentials by assuming the role.  Creates an Amazon S3 Service client object with the temporary credentials.
6. Deletes the resources.

Follow this example.

[Create an IAM user and assume a role with AWS STS using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/iam_example_iam_Scenario_CreateUserAssumeRole_section.html)

If you prefer to see it in Github -- see:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/iam/src/main/java/com/example/iam/IAMScenario.java